# Is Extent report version 5 now available or not?

Tags: selenium, extentreports, selenium-extent-report

Extent report version 5.0.0 and 5.0.1 available in mvnrepository.com but documentation not available in extentreports.com. Explain me it is the real update or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The extent reports [github page](http://%20https://github.com/extent-framework/extentreports-java) for java says:

> Documentation
> Documentation for ExtentReports 5.x is hosted on GitHub at ExtentReports Wiki.
> For versions 4 and below, visit extentreports.com.

You can start your journey into v5 docs from the what's new:
[https://github.com/extent-framework/extentreports-java/wiki/What's-New](https://github.com/extent-framework/extentreports-java/wiki/What%27s-New)